# Deleted database automaticaly restore without my action

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

i've a problem with an Azure Database. I've deleted a month ago a DB but the problem is that DB automatically restore without my permission or action (and with an high price plan ). I haven't any auto restore scenario and when i check the log, the restoration of the DB was triggered by nothing...
Can some one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the **Deleted Databases** , whether your DB is deleted properly or not.
Check the Activity Log of the resource group where the Azure SQL Server is Deployed.

[image]

If Activity Log also shows **restored by nothing** ,please raise a ticket with [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/).

Comment: Yes my DB deleting is set to sucess and i've few days ago an "Update sucessful and when i open JSon of the operation, i've "Create the DB xxxxx ...." and Caller "Unvailable".

Comment: Please raise a ticket with [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/).